# Storing Inherited classes in Generic Lists - suggestions please

Tags: c#, generic-list

I'm building a simple shape designer it's simple enough - add shapes to an area and you can resize them and move them by dragging and dropping - think the form designer in VS.

At present I have a base class of Shape which represents common properties (Location, Size) and methods. Other classes representing objects on the designer inherit from Shape e.g. Circle, Square etc. I store the objects in a generic list e.g. `List<Shape>`

My question is about List vs. other generic data structures, and when to use them.

**Edit**: Thanks to Mathias for pointing out what I really meant.

Cheers

Comment: to state whether or not it's 'best', please at least inform us what are your concerns and what do you believe are your alternatives.

Comment: What I mean is I have done this thing using generic lists, and was wondering what other ways could it done? I read somewhere that using generic lists in this way was not a particularly efficient way of doing things.

Comment: Is your questions about the List<T> vs. other generic data structures, or about something else?

Comment: Mathias, that's exactly what I meant!

Comment: Unless you need something 'uncommon' the List<T> is usually the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is this: is the best way to store the shapes? if not why not?

It really depends.  One of the main concerns should be how you are using the list of shapes.  The speed of access, insertion, and removal will change depending on the type of collection you use.

For example:

- If you access by index is your main concern, then `List<T>` is appropriate.
- If you're just iterating, but need to add and remove shapes frequently, then `LinkedList<T>` or a similar structure *may* be beneficial.  This provides fast enumeration, but much quick insert or removal than a `List<T>` (especially if you're removing from the middle of the list).

Comment: You read my mind! That's very helpful and what I was looking for. Thanks.